# Excel: Pivot Table - Percentage of one value from another

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

My pivot table has 3 columns:

- Row label (expand/collapse items in each row)
- Count of Case
- Count of Assigned

My DATA sheet has 2 sets of data:

- "Case" (line item for every bug, feature, etc.)
- "Assigned" (name of the person assigned to the case)

On the pivot table, how do I display a column that effectively displays ***"X is Y % of Z"*** (assigned/case as percent)?

***Example:*** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M16Z.jpg

In the linked image, ***Case (Z) is '10'*** and ***Assigned (X) is '3'***. A third column should display **"*30%*" (Y)**.

I've tried Calculated Field and even reduced "Assigned" to a 1 or 0 on the DATA sheet (as a pseudo "True" or "False", and then using that data in the Pivot Table) - all to no avail.

Please help! I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you cannot use    count() in the calculated fields.  I would try to manipulate the source data so that you are summing numbers and not counting 'names'.  Then, create a calculated field as shown below:

[image]

Comment: First, I really appreciate that you had a look and gave it a shot! I really tried searching around and called several people - all with no luck. In the back of my mind, I suspected it was trying to calc using the underlying values and not the counts themselves. 
  
  
So, I tried what you've suggested and the result is that the field shows "1" the whole way down. 
  
  
http://i.imgur.com/JxDsWbj.jpg
  
  
Changing the "Show Value As" generally has no impact.

Comment: Thanks again. I wanted to avoid this solution but it does seem to be the path of least resistance.

I really appreciate it!